# How many ways between 2000 and 5000 can be written from the digits 2,3,4,5,7 if: a. no digit is repeated b. digits must be repeated?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many ways between 2000 and 5000 can be written from the digits 2,3,4,5,7if: a. no digit is repeated b. digits must be repeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You have 3 choices for the left-most digit (2,3, or 4); and then 4 choices for the second, 3 for the third, and 2 choices for the last digit. This gives a total of 72 numbers.

b) # of numbers with a digit repeated = (total # of numbers built from 2,3,4,5,7) - (# of numbers with no repeated digits) 
And then we can compute: total # of numbers built from 2,3,4,5,7 = (choices for first digit) x (choices for first digit) x (choices for first digit) x (choices for first digit) = 3*5*5*5 = 375. Thus, the answer is 375 - 72 = 302 numbers.